# how to validate dynamically added controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am adding some controls in my page while loading page.

Some of them are required, so I add requiredfieldvalidator control with them also.

But when I do postback using button click, at that time this dynamically added controls are not validated.

I am not able to understand what is wrong.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
 Panel pn = new Panel();
RadTextBox rdts = new RadTextBox {
                           ID = "txt" + txField.ColumnName,
                           Width = 200
                        };

                        pn.Controls.Add(rdts);

RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator {
                        ControlToValidate = "txt" + txField.ColumnName,
                        Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
                        Text = "*",
                        ValidationGroup = "standard",
                        ID = "val" + txField.ColumnName,
                        Visible = true
                     };

                     pn.Controls.Add(rfv);
additionalDataPanel.Controls.Add(pn);
}

protected void ClickOK(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (Page.IsValid){
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: what is additionalDataPanel? is another panel?

Comment: Yes it is my main panel of page.

Comment: First find the ids that are created dynamically(by using viewsource in browser).using javascript,theirs ids you can validate them

Comment: You mean to say that requiredfieldvalidator will not work in this case ?

Comment: Why do you create the controls dynamically instead of just setting their visibility? Adding controls dynamically usually adds a lot of complexity that can be avoided in most cases. It will most likely save you some trouble if you find another way (visibility, Repeaters, ...) to implement your requirements.

Comment: Actually I have dropdown list for which there might be different controls which comes from database. So I have to add them dynamically only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

delete

```
ValidationGroup = "standard"
```

from RequiredFieldValidator 
or add to text box

```
ValidationGroup = "standard"
```